# Why nativewind styles doesn't work if the styling is done at component level?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tailwind-css

React-native styling using **Nativewind** works fine if the styling is done at App.Js. Like here:

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <View>
      <Text className = "text-red-500">Hello</Text>
    </View>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

But if the styling is done at component level, then it doesn't work anymore.

```
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <HomeScreen/>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

HomeScreen Component:

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text className = "text-red-500">Hello</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to tell nativewind the locations of where your components reside by adding this to your tailwind.config.ts

```
content: ["./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./<custom directory such as src>/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
```

reference: https://www.nativewind.dev/quick-starts/react-native-cli

Answer (score 1):

If you setup folder in tailwind.config.js and still not work then delete `nodemodule` then install it again and it will work.

This works for me:

```
content: ["./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./<custom directory such as src>/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"]
```